# how to get current time in razor view using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried many ways mentioned below but none of them is working

```
var currentTime = Date.parse(date + ' ' + currentDate.getHours() + ':' + currentDate.getMinutes() + ':' + currentDate.getSeconds());

var t = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")

DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay  etc
```

thanks in advance

Comment: current time in razor or in javascript? both are different

Comment: Are you sure you know what is razor exactly? It is a view engine. In C#, `DateTime.Now` returns local time and `DateTime.UtcNow` returns UTC time.

Comment: yes, in view engine I want to get current time

Comment: var date = currentDate.getMonth() + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear();
            var currentTime = Date.parse(date + ' ' + currentDate.getHours() + ':' + currentDate.getMinutes() + ':' + currentDate.getSeconds());
            var startTime = Date.parse(date + ' ' + '@ViewData["StartTime"]');
            var endtime = Date.parse(date + ' ' + '@ViewData["EndTime"]');

Comment: In this code currentTime is not giving the time

Comment: @KhawajaUmairLiaquat Can you please post the Razor + Javascript view code excerpt on how you are trying to get and display date?

Answer (score 0):

try using this function..

```
function $dateTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var dd = d.getDate();
    var mm = d.getMonth()+1;//January is 0!
    var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
    var h=d.getHours();
    var m=d.getMinutes();
    var s=d.getSeconds();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd}
    if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} 
    if(h<10){h='0'+h} 
    if(m<10){m='0'+m} 
    if(s<10){s='0'+s} 
    return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}
```

returns the value 2015-01-06 and current time..